# jenkins version conflict with findbugs

Tags: jenkins, findbugs

i am getting the following thing every time i start jenkins.i couldn't get hudson findbugs graph even though i activate it.

Manage Old Data

When there are changes in how data is stored on disk, Jenkins uses the following strategy: data is migrated to the new structure when it is loaded, but the file is not resaved in the new format. This allows for downgrading Jenkins if needed. However, it can also leave data on disk in the old format indefinitely. The table below lists files containing such data, and the Jenkins version(s) where the data structure was changed.

Sometimes errors occur while reading data (if a plugin adds some data and that plugin is later disabled, if migration code is not written for structure changes, or if Jenkins is downgraded after it has already written data not readable by the older version). These errors are logged, but the unreadable data is then skipped over, allowing Jenkins to startup and function properly.

Type    Name    Version 
The form below may be used to resave these files in the current format. Doing so means a downgrade to a Jenkins release older than the selected version will not be able to read the data stored in the new format. Note that simply using Jenkins to create and configure jobs and run builds can save data that may not be readable by older Jenkins releases, even when this form is not used. Also if any unreadable data errors are reported in the right side of the table above, note that this data will be lost when the file is resaved.

Eventually the code supporting these data migrations may be removed. Compatibility will be retained for at least 150 releases since the structure change. Versions older than this are in bold above, and it is recommended to resave these files.

No old data was found.
Unreadable Data

It is acceptable to leave unreadable data in these files, as Jenkins will safely ignore it. To avoid the log messages at Jenkins startup you can permanently delete the unreadable data by resaving these files using the button below.

Type    Name    Error
hudson.maven.MavenModuleSet nov 7 latest    NonExistentFieldException: No such field hudson.plugins.findbugs.FindBugsReporter.isRankActivated

Discard Unreadable Data

Comment: So what is your question?  Is it causing problems?  Is something not working?

Comment: ya i am not getting hudson findbugs graph.it is showing xmlparser error in console output.couldn't parse findbugs.xml...please refer to my earlier post for error.

Answer (score 0):

According to the main FindBugs author, this is expected behavior when you downgrade FindBugs from a newer version to an older one:

> Once you upgrade to a new version you can't downgrade without getting 
>   such kind of exceptions (I only ensure backward compatibility). Can't 
>   you use the "manage old data wizard" in Jenkins to remove these new 
>   fields from your persisted Jenkins build files?

[Nabble discussion](http://jenkins.361315.n4.nabble.com/No-such-field-hudson-plugins-findbugs-FindBugsReporter-isRankActivated-td3646152.html).